# CSS loaded but empty

Tags: html, css

I'm currently testing to modify .htmls with Powershell. Which works fine.
Only problem I'm having (for now) is, that the CSS appears to be empty after loaded.

[image: FF Developer]

Firefox shows, that the .css is loaded but in Firebug it says (roughly translated) "No style rules where defined. You can create rules"

[image: Firebug]

My head:

```
<head>
    <title>Phantom by HTML5 UP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

I'm currently working on a Xampp.

Edit1: I tried with Firefox and Chrome

Edit2: main.css does contain code and I tried with another .css

Comment: Silly question, but the css file does contain code, right?

Comment: Do you have some CSS code in main.css?

Comment: That's not a silly question at all. Should have mentioned it from the start: yes, it does contain code.

Comment: Does your CSS file contains `<style>` tag? Can you provide live example of this file?

Comment: did you try to open in new tab ? maybe the path is wrong, but xampp doesn't throw error

Comment: `main.css` is loaded with a status of 304 (not modified) - If you're trying multiple times, try clearing the cache. You may fix your problem and not even know it.

Comment: Does the console show anything?

Comment: What does your css file look like?

Comment: @Justinas: it doesn't. I'm using a template created by s.o. else cause I'm mainly playing around with powershell. So posting the 3k row main.css wouldn't be helpfull ^^
But I get the same prob with a test.css containing only
`h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color:red;
}`

@IE5Master @ J. Titus: didn't help

Comment: Is the Path correct? Did you try it with a leading slash?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: Path should be correct. Developer Tool shows no error. I tried renaming the main.css without changing the path in the head and the Firefox development tool showed a 404.